# la funcion en onclick se ejecuta sin hacer click

Tags: javascript

Estoy con un ejercicio en el que debo mostrar los atributos modelo, placa y dueño de una clase. He metido en un onclick la función para mostrar pero se ejecuta sin hacer click. También he probado quitando el argumento "todos" del onclick y colocándolo en la función mostrar, pero así ni siquiera enviaba los datos.
 Entiendo, entonces, que para presentar las funciones en los eventos no se deben mostrar los argumentos. Pero, entonces cómo puedo presentar una función de este tipo?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="">
    <input type="text" id="marca" placeholder="marca">
    <input type="text" id="modelo" placeholder="modelo">
    <input type="text" id="placa" placeholder="placa">
    <input type="text" id="color" placeholder="color">
    <input type="text" id="duenho" placeholder="duenho">
    <button type="button" id="boton">enviar</button>
    <button type="button" id="ver">todos</button>
</form>
    <script>
        class Automovil{
            constructor(marca, modelo, placa, color, duenho){
                this.marca = marca;
                this.modelo = modelo;
                this.placa = placa;
                this.color = color;
                this.duenho = duenho;
            }

            todos = Array();

            get marca(){
                return this._marca;
            }

            set marca(x){
                this._marca = x;
            }

            get modelo(){
                return this._modelo;
            }

            set modelo(x){
                this._modelo = x;
            }

            get placa(){
                return this._placa;
            }

            set placa(x){
                this._placa = x}

            get color(){
                return this._color;
            }

            set color(x){
                this._color = x;
            }

            get duenho(){
                return this._duenho;
            }

            set duenho(x){
                this._duenho = x;
            }

        }

        function crear(){
            var brand = document.getElementById("marca").value;
            var model = document.getElementById("modelo").value;
            var numberPlate = document.getElementById("placa").value;
            var colors = document.getElementById("color").value;
            var owner = document.getElementById("duenho").value;

            nuevo = new Automovil(brand, model, numberPlate, colors, owner);
            todos.push(nuevo);
        }

        function mostrar(x){
            var indice = x.length -1;
            for($i = 0; $i <= indice; $i++){
                var uno = todos[$i]._modelo + " " + todos[$i]._placa + " " + todos[$i]._duenho + ('\n');

                document.write(uno + "<br>");
            }
        }

        var ford = new Automovil("ford", "fiesta", "1234hh", "azul", "Paco");
        var opel = new Automovil("opel", "corsa", "6543as", "rojo", "Pepe");
        todos = [ford, opel];

        boton.onclick = crear;
        ver.onclick = mostrar(todos);

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Como siempre, mil gracias

Comment: Coloca tu HTML por favor

Comment: Hecho  :D
Gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He añadido el siguiente bloque de código que te hacía falta para poder ejecutar las funciones del `onclick`

```
    var boton = document.getElementById('boton');
    var ver = document.getElementById('ver');

    boton.onclick = crear;
    ver.onclick = function() {
      mostrar(todos);
    };
```

El problema que tenías era que estabas llamando directamente `boton` sin tener en cuenta que la variable no la habías definido, lo cual se hace simplemente con

`var boton;`

Lo siguiente que te hacía falta era asignar a esta variable botón el elemento del DOM (o de tu HTML). Para esto utilizas la funcuón  `document.getElementById(<nombre_del_elemento>)`, aquí colocas el valor del ID que tienes definido en tu HTML, en este caso coincide con el nombre de la variable, pero en sí podría ser cualquier nombre, con esto estás enlazando tu HTML con tu Javascript.

Una vez haces esta relación ya puedes agregar eventos a tu variable. Para el caso de los eventos asignas funciones a los eventos las cuáles se ejecutarán cuando el evento se dispare. Anterior mente tenías este código

```
ver.onclick = mostrar(todos)
```

Lo cual asignaba el resultado de la ejecución de la función `mostrar(todos)` y esta al no tener ningún valor de retorno, daba por valor `undefined` por lo que cada vez que el evento se disparaba este intentaría ejecutar un `undefined`, lo cual no tiene sentido. Por esto deberías envolver esta ejecución con otra función para que esta ejecute la función mostrar cuando el evento suceda.

El código corregido final quedaría así:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="">
    <input type="text" id="marca" placeholder="marca">
    <input type="text" id="modelo" placeholder="modelo">
    <input type="text" id="placa" placeholder="placa">
    <input type="text" id="color" placeholder="color">
    <input type="text" id="duenho" placeholder="duenho">
    <button type="button" id="boton">enviar</button>
    <button type="button" id="ver">todos</button>
</form>
    <script>
        class Automovil{
            constructor(marca, modelo, placa, color, duenho){
                this.marca = marca;
                this.modelo = modelo;
                this.placa = placa;
                this.color = color;
                this.duenho = duenho;
            }

            todos = Array();

            get marca(){
                return this._marca;
            }

            set marca(x){
                this._marca = x;
            }

            get modelo(){
                return this._modelo;
            }

            set modelo(x){
                this._modelo = x;
            }

            get placa(){
                return this._placa;
            }

            set placa(x){
                this._placa = x}

            get color(){
                return this._color;
            }

            set color(x){
                this._color = x;
            }

            get duenho(){
                return this._duenho;
            }

            set duenho(x){
                this._duenho = x;
            }

        }

        function crear(){
            var brand = document.getElementById("marca").value;
            var model = document.getElementById("modelo").value;
            var numberPlate = document.getElementById("placa").value;
            var colors = document.getElementById("color").value;
            var owner = document.getElementById("duenho").value;

            nuevo = new Automovil(brand, model, numberPlate, colors, owner);
            todos.push(nuevo);
        }

        function mostrar(x){
            var indice = x.length -1;
            for($i = 0; $i <= indice; $i++){
                var uno = todos[$i]._modelo + " " + todos[$i]._placa + " " + todos[$i]._duenho + ('\n');

                document.write(uno + "<br>");
            }
        }

        var ford = new Automovil("ford", "fiesta", "1234hh", "azul", "Paco");
        var opel = new Automovil("opel", "corsa", "6543as", "rojo", "Pepe");
        todos = [ford, opel];

        var boton = document.getElementById('boton');
        var ver = document.getElementById('ver');

        boton.onclick = crear;
        ver.onclick = function() {
          mostrar(todos);
        };

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Daniel, muy bien explicado

:D